# Python Matplotlib. Patches

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, pyqt5, patch

[image]Is there any way to fill my  new created rectangle patch with GRID?
I am trying to create a grid inside the rectangle which is being created by mouse clicks.
Is there any way of creating a grid inside the patch?

class events:

```
def __init__(self, cv):

    self.canvas = cv
    self.axes = self.canvas.axes



    self.rect = Rectangle((0,0),1,1)


    self.axes.add_patch(self.rect)

    self.x0 = None
    self.y0 = None
    self.x1 = None
    self.y1 = None  


def on_press(self, event):

    self.x0,self.y0 = self.canvas.m(event.xdata,event.ydata, inverse=True)




def on_release(self, event):

    self.x1 = event.xdata
    self.y1 = event.ydata

    self.rect.set_width(self.x1 - self.x0)
    self.rect.set_height(self.y1 - self.y0)
    self.rect.set_xy((self.x0, self.y0))
    self.rect.set_color('orange')
    self.rect.set_edgecolor('black')
```

Comment: Could you explain what you want to get, maybe an image will help. On the other hand you should provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I have added a picture. I want where the organge patch appears, to be appeared with a grid inside this patch as well.